# Remove repeated elements from list and HTML Tag

Tags: python

I have list like this:

```
 [' name           = Badmash Gujjar\n',
 ' image          = \n',
 ' image          =\n',
 ' caption        =\n', 
 ' director       = Sameer Butt\n',
 ' producer       =\n',
 ' writer         = Nasir Adeeb\n',
 ' starring       = Saima<br>Shaan (actor)Shaan<br>',
 ' music          = Robin Ghosh\n',
 ' cinematography =\n',
 ' editing        =\n', 
 ' distributor    = \n',
 ' released       = Film date2001']
```

I want to remove repeated elements from list.  I tried following code, but not found any luck. `list(set(l))`.

Also is there any way to remove HTML tag? thanks

Comment: From a string point of view, `' image          = \n'` and `' image          =\n'` are **not** the same. That's why your, otherwise correct, method does not show you what you probably await.

Comment: @eumiro thanks. I'm removing `whitespaces` from list. Then I will try again. thanks

Comment: @eumiro Its does not matter on `right side`. I want if repeated element found on `left side`, then remove it also its value. thanks

Comment: if you want to have unique keys (the left side) and save the corresponding values, then the dictionary is the solution you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = dict(map(str.strip, a.split('=', 1)) for a in l)
```

will create the following dictionary (which is probably what you want, since a dictionary doesn't have repeated keys):

```
{'caption': '',
 'cinematography': '',
 'director': 'Sameer Butt',
 'distributor': '',
 'editing': '',
 'image': '',
 'music': 'Robin Ghosh',
 'name': 'Badmash Gujjar',
 'producer': '',
 'released': 'Film date2001',
 'starring': 'Saima<br>Shaan (actor)Shaan<br>',
 'writer': 'Nasir Adeeb'}
```

If you want to remove the `<br>` tags only, then you can use this:

```
d = dict(map(lambda x: x.strip().replace('<br>', ''), a.split('=', 1)) for a in l)
```

If you need to remove *any* HTML tags, a more complicated regular expression (or HTML parser) is needed.

Comment: Thanks But i need result only in list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick one liner made just to convey the idea .. when you use it for production make the script more readable .. Where l is your list..

```
dict([tuple(map(lambda a:a.strip().replace('<br>',''),x.split("="))) for x in l])
```